# elmah on IIS 6 box

Tags: iis-6, elmah

I've got a web site with elmah running on it logging to a sql box.  In my test env it's a IIS 7 machine and all works well.  When i upload to a network solutions web running IIS 6 I get an error

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +58
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CheckPermissionAllowed(String configKey, Boolean requirePermission, Boolean isTrustedWithoutAptca) +99
```

The website is setup to run .net 3.5.  All of our pages work fine, but elmah gives this error.  I've done some searching but can't find what i've setup incorrectly.  Was hoping someone else has already solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your hoster is running ASP.NET in Medium Trust. There's a couple of things to try.

Add the `requirePermission="false"` attribute to each of the Elmah configuration sections declared in your `web.config`, for example:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" 
           requirePermission="false"/>
  <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" 
           requirePermission="false"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

If this doesn't work you could also try overriding the trust level by adding this to `<system.web>` in your `web.config` file:

```
<trust level="Full"/>
```

If this doesn't work then you may need to contact your hoster and ask them to relax their trust policy. However if your site is in a shared pool it's unlikely that they'll entertain this.

**Update:**

About the `requirePermission` attribute: The default Medium Trust policy doesn't permit partially trusted callers access to configuration file settings, even in your own application.

You can elect to override this for your application's local configuration settings by setting `requirePermission="false"`. This is done in the `<section name="..." type="..." />` declarations in your `web.config` file. So, when you set:

```
<section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" 
       requirePermission="false"/
```

Effectively what your saying is please grant Elmah permission to read this setting:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.VistaDBErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ElmahDB" />
```

Comment: that did the trick.. thank you for the help.  so the requiredpermission.. what exactly does it apply to